# JavaFX And Sockets: Chatroom Glitchy, works sometimes

Tags: java, sockets, javafx, server, client

I have a server, client, and main menu class that all work together to make a chat room using sockets, but it doesn't always work. It is very glitchy. Sometimes it will send the message through all clients and sometimes it will only post to the local client. Sometimes instead of posting the message and name of user it only posts the name twice.

I think that the server class is the one that is broken, or that the sockets are all passing the wrong information but I am not sure. Any help to a fix would be great. Thanks!

```
public class Server{

//Var's That User Inputs
private static String IP;
public static String MESSAGE;

//Hard-Coded Var's
public static int MaxUsers = 12;

private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static int PORT = 25570;
private static PrintWriter out;
private static BufferedReader in;
public static Socket socket;

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

    System.out.println("Starting Server...");

    try {//Gets Server IP
        InetAddress iAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        IP = iAddress.getHostAddress();
        System.out.println("Server IP address : "+IP);
        System.out.println("Server Port: "+PORT);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Exceptioni "+e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    //Starting Server Socket
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    System.out.println("Server Started.");

    while(true){

    socket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("Client Accepted."); 

    for(int i = 0;i < MaxUsers; i++){

    System.out.println("IP Connection from: "+socket.getInetAddress());
    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    if(Users.user[i]==null){
        Users.user[i] = new Users(out,in,Users.user);
    Thread thread = new Thread(Users.user[i]);
    thread.start();
    break;  
            }

        }

    }

}

public static String getServerIP(){
    try {
        InetAddress iAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        IP = iAddress.getHostAddress();   
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

    }
    return IP;
}

}

class Users implements Runnable{
String MESSAGE;
PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;
static Users[] user = new Users[Server.MaxUsers];
String name;

public Users(PrintWriter out, BufferedReader in, Users[] user){
    this.out = out;
    this.in = in;
    this.user = user;
}

public void run(){
    try {
        name = in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    while(true){
        try {
            MESSAGE = in.readLine();

        for(int i=0;i<Server.MaxUsers;i++){
            if(user[i] != null){
                    user[i].out.println(name+": "+MESSAGE);
                } 
            }
        } catch(IOException e){
            this.out = null;
            this.in = null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Client Class

```
public class Client {

//Var's That User Inputs
static String MESSAGE;
private static String IP;
public static PrintWriter out;
public static BufferedReader in;
public static boolean Connected;

//Hard-Coded Var's
private static int PORT = 25570;
private static Socket socket;
public static String name;
public static String MessageFromPlayer;

public static void main() throws IOException{

    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        ChatBox input = new ChatBox(in);
        Thread thread = new Thread(input);
        thread.start();        


    name = MainMenu.name;
    out.println(name);
    boolean thisBool = true;
    while(thisBool == true){
        MessageFromPlayer = MainMenu.MessageFromPlayer;
        out.println(MessageFromPlayer);
        thisBool = false;
}
}
public static boolean Connect(){
    System.out.println("Verifying Server IP Adress...");
    try {
        socket = new Socket(MainMenu.IP, PORT);
        System.out.println("Connection To "+ MainMenu.IP +" Successful...");

        if(socket.isConnected()){
            return Connected = true;
                }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return Connected;
}

}
class ChatBox implements Runnable{
static String MessageFromServer;
static BufferedReader in;

public ChatBox(BufferedReader in){
    ChatBox.in = in;
}
public void run() {
    boolean thisBool = true;
    while(thisBool  == true){
    try {
        MessageFromServer = in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    thisBool = false;
    }
}
public static String getServerMessage(){
    try {
        MessageFromServer = in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return MessageFromServer;
}
}
```

Main Menu Class, This Is What You Run To Run The Client.

```
public class MainMenu extends Application {

static DataInputStream in;
static String IP;
static String MessageFromPlayer;
static String name;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Pane p1 = new Pane();//Applicatino>Stage>Scene>Pane;
    Pane p2 = new Pane();
    Pane p3 = new Pane();
    Pane p4 = new Pane();

    Label l1 = new Label("IP: ");
    Label l2 = new Label("Chat: ");
    Label l3 = new Label("UserName: ");
    TextField t1 = new TextField();
    TextField t2 = new TextField();
    TextField t3 = new TextField();
    TextArea a1 = new TextArea();
    a1.setEditable(false);

    Scene s1 = new Scene(p1,960, 540);
    Scene s2 = new Scene(p2,960, 540);
    Scene s3 = new Scene(p3,960, 540);
    Scene s4 = new Scene(p4,960, 540);
    Button b1 = new Button("SinglePlayer");
    Button b2 = new Button("MultiPlayer");
    Button b3 = new Button("Connect");
    Button b4 = new Button("Enter");

    p1.getChildren().add(b1);
    p1.getChildren().add(b2);

    p2.getChildren().add(l1);
    p2.getChildren().add(l3);
    p2.getChildren().add(t1);
    p2.getChildren().add(t3);
    p2.getChildren().add(b3);

    p3.getChildren().add(l2);
    p3.getChildren().add(t2);
    p3.getChildren().add(a1);
    p3.getChildren().add(b4);

    //Item Layout
    b1.setLayoutX(380);//TODO: Fix layout, division by max size
    b1.setLayoutY(270);

    b2.setLayoutX(560);
    b2.setLayoutY(270);

    l1.setLayoutX(438);
    l1.setLayoutY(270);

    l2.setLayoutX(100);
    l2.setLayoutY(485);

    t1.setLayoutX(455);
    t1.setLayoutY(270);

    t2.setLayoutX(100);
    t2.setLayoutY(500);

    b3.setLayoutX(455);
    b3.setLayoutY(300);

    a1.setLayoutX(100);
    a1.setLayoutY(100);

    b4.setLayoutX(250);
    b4.setLayoutY(500);

    l3.setLayoutX(395);
    l3.setLayoutY(230);

    t3.setLayoutX(455);
    t3.setLayoutY(230);

    //Button Listeners
    b1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            public void handle(ActionEvent event){
                System.out.println("Single Player Starting...");
                primaryStage.hide();
                engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(null);   
        }
    });
    b2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent event){
            System.out.println("Multi Player Starting...");
            primaryStage.setScene(s2);

    }
});
    b3.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent event){
            try {
                name = t3.getText();
                IP = t1.getText();
                Client.Connect();
                if(Client.Connected == true){
                    primaryStage.setScene(s3);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
});
    b4.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent event){

            MessageFromPlayer = t2.getText();

                try {
                    Client.main();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            a1.insertText(0, ChatBox.getServerMessage()+"\n");
            t2.clear();
    }
});

    primaryStage.setScene(s1);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Client Starting.");
    launch(args);

}
}
```

Comment: Did you get any exception? Do you have any idea which part of code is causing problem? You provide too much code...

Comment: I didnt get an exception, and sorry. I believe that the Server is glitching out. when multiple clients connect to it the server cant distinguish between messages and names I dont know why